# showing selected names in a <div> by using a javascript array

Tags: javascript, cometd

I have a div which displays name of the people who are online, I have the following members in
the div

```
<div id="members">
<span>Amlan Karmakar</span>
<span>Atin Roy</span>
<span>Arpan Burman</span>
<span>Ramanuj Mukherjee</span>
</div>
```

I have another javascript array `friends[]`, which has `'Amlan Karmakar'` and `'Ramanuj Mukherjee'` has friends, I want to display  those members who are in the `friends[]` array, I am inserting the name of the friends by `friends.push("Amlan Karmakar")`. The names in div are auto generated by cometd chat, I have written the names in the div for simplicity. I hope there is a solution to this problem. [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623841/showing-selected-user-in-cometd-chat) didn't solve my problem.

Comment: So you want to put the data from the friends[] array into the `<div id="members">`?

Comment: Yes sort of, I want only those names to show in the `<div>` which are there in the `friends[]` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the below, i.e. split the HTML of the div containing the members, loop through them and check if they are in the friendsArray. Note that this is a rough implementation, and that it assumes a reasonably new browser as it uses Ecmascript 5 features. The concept can applied using old-fashioned `for` loops too.

```
var all = document.getElementById('members').getElementsByTagName('span');
var friendsOnly = '';
for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++){
    if(friendsArray.some(function(friend){
        return friend == all[i].innerHTML;
    })){
        friendsOnly += '<span>' + all[i].innerHTML + '</span>';
    }
});
all.innerHTML(friendsOnly);
```

By the way, I'm assuming the friendsArray may contain people who are not already in the div. If that is not the case, then I'm not sure what the question is about.

Comment: What does the parameter `member`  inside the anonymous function do, since I am relatively new to javascript so I having problem understanding it.

Comment: The split() splits the innerHTML of the members div into an array. The forEach function is invoked on that array, and the callback function which is a parameter to forEach() receives the value of the current array index as its parameter. So on first invocation it will be 'Amlan Karmakar', on second it will be 'Atin Roy' and so on.

Comment: I just saw view source of the page, it turns out that names are inside the `<div>` are included in a `<span>`. Do I need to update anything in the code since the names are inside a `<span>`. I have updated my question

Comment: Yes, then I think it requires a different approach, as parsing HTML with regular expressions is not a good idea (a string with a few <br/> was ok I thought). I have updated my answer to loop through the span elements and compare their innerHTML to the names in the friendsArray now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get only the friends out of the list of members:

```
var friendMembers = document.getElementById('members').split(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi)
      .filter(function(member) { return (friends.indexOf(member) > -1) } );
```

Comment: You are trying to split the div DOM element itself, instead of its contents. And I guess the members div will contain `<br/>` rather than line breaks. Otherwise nice and concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

> So you want to put the data from the friends[] array into the `<div id="members">`
>
> *I want only those names to show in the  which are there in the friends[] array*

If you only want to display the names which are in the friends array, as you suggested in your comment, I suppose this will do the trick:

```
var target = document.getElementById("members");

// Remove this line if you want to keep the current names in the members div.
target.innerHTML = ""; // Clean before inserting friends

for (var i = 0; i <= friends.length; i++) {
    target.innerHTML += friends[i] + "<br />"; // Add friend + break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try knockout.js, this framework will help you handle this case.